# Error when pushing to github repository cloned using a token

Tags: git, github

I have a script that installs new VMs using code cloned from a private github repository using a read-only access token like this:

```
git clone https://0123456789abcdef@github.com/<organization>/<project>
```

I can commit changes to this code, but when I try to push I get this error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://0123456789abcdef@github.com/<organization>/<project>/' not found
```

How can I commit without upgrading the token to have write access to the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the URL of the repository used for push operations only:

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/<organization>/<project>/
```

Then if you push you will be prompted for a github login and password, but fetch operations will continue to work without authentication.